Regarding the issue of React page routing
My page is like this: configure routing in the startup component
This Home is my starting component：
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar, Sidebar } from "./views/test.js";
import "./css/app.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BlogPost } from "./views/blog.js";

export default function Home() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/blog">About</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Nav/>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/blog">
                <BlogPost/>
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }

When I access through 'http://localhost:3000/', this error occurs
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Home`.

My directory structure is like this
├─node_modules
├─public
├─src
│  └─app
│     ├─api
│     ├─css
│     ├─router
│     ├─views
│     ├─Layout.js
│     └─page.js -> func Home()
├─README.md      
├─next.config.mjs  
├─package-lock.json  
├─postcss.config.mjs
├─jsconfig.json 
├─package.json
└─tailwind.config.js

For the front-end, I am a beginner and I don't know how to modify it
ps:
My GitHub
The following are the components mentioned
BlogPost:
import "../css/blog.css";
import { get_article_by_id } from "../api/server.js";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";

function Article(props) {
  // console.log( "[debug] props.content is "+ typeof props.content);
  // console.log( "[debug] props.content : "+ props.content);
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown className="md_title" children={props.title} />
      <ReactMarkdown
        className="md_content"
        children={props.content}
        remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
        components={{
          code(props) {
            const { children, className, node, ...rest } = props;
            const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || "");
            return match ? (
              <SyntaxHighlighter
                {...rest}
                PreTag="div"
                children={String(children).replace(/\n$/, "")}
                language={match[1]}
                style={dark}
              />
            ) : (
              <code {...rest} className={className}>
                {children}
              </code>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function BlogPost() {
  // let { id } = useParams();
  let id = "101";
  const article = await get_article_by_id(id);
  console.log(article);
  return (
    <div className="md_main_vertical">
      <div className="md_main_horizontal">
        <Article title={article.title} content={article.content} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Nav:
'use client'
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import "../css/test.css";

export function Navbar({ sidebarOpen, toggleSidebar }) {
  return (
    <header className="navbar">
      <button className="menu-button" onClick={toggleSidebar}>
        {sidebarOpen ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
      </button>
      <h1>Menghan Studio</h1>
    </header>
  );
}

export function Sidebar({ sidebarOpen }) {
  return (
      <div>
      <nav className={`sidebar ${sidebarOpen ? "open" : ""}`}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Nav() {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setSidebarOpen(!sidebarOpen);
  };
  return (
    <nav>
      <Navbar sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen} toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
      <Sidebar sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen} />
    </nav>
  );
}



You don't appear to have react-router-dom installed as a project dependency. At least it isn't included in your package.json file. I am certain you should be seeing different errors, but maybe you aren't depending on your dev stack. Try adding (e.g. installing) react-router-dom@5 as a project dependency and re-build/run/deploy your app.

Actually, after forking your repo it would appear you have many missing dependencies. Just go through your code and ensure you properly add/install all of them.

You have to import following on main.js and wrap App component
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
<Router>
    <App />
</Router>

then, in your app component
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
<Routes>
  <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/blog" element={<BlogPost />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>

then define MainLayout
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
<div>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
</div>

make sure you follow your style guide and don't just copy and paste this it won't work. Take an idea here create and import all necessary files and implement others by yourself.
